# stub files present in package, still mypy complains: Cannot find implementation

Tags: python, types, mypy, stub

### package 1

I created a package `my_utils` and generated the stud files with the mypy utility `stubgen`

```sh
stubgen -p my_utils
# >>> Processed 2 modules
# >>> Generated files under out/my_utils/
```

moved the stubs to the package root dir

```sh
mv out/my_utils/* my_utils
```

mypy is happy about all

```sh
mypy my_utils
# >>> # Success: no issues found in 2 source files
```

### package 2

package 2 have my_utils as a dependency so I installed my `my_utils` using poetry

```sh
poetry add git+ssh://git@github.com/username/my-utils.git
```

my virtual env library have the giving me the following package structure:

```sh
my_utils
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyi
├── os.py
├── os.pyi
└── py.typed
```

but still mypy complains when i check my package 2

```sh
mypy r26/bwf_converter.py
# r26/bwf_converter.py:12: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "my_utils.os"
```

`__init__.pyi` is empty and os.pyi has the following:

```py
import csv
import json
from typing import Dict, List, Literal, Union

OutputProc = Literal["wait", "raw", "json", "csv", ""]
StdType = Literal["stderr", "stdout"]
JsonContent = Dict[str, str]
CsvContent = List[Dict[str, str]]

class PopenWrapper:
    cmd: Union[str, List[str]]
    ouput_proc: Literal["wait", "raw", "json", "csv", ""]
    log_output: bool
    kwargs: Dict[str, str]
    def __init__(self, cmd: Union[str, List[str]], ouput_proc: OutputProc = ..., log_output: bool = ..., **kwargs: Dict[str, str]) -> None: ...
    def run(self) -> Union[bool, str, CsvContent, JsonContent]: ...
```

If anyone could hint me about what Am I doing wrong...

Comment: Can you provide a link to your GitHub source code? That will help people better troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot, install and use `pyright`. If you use `vscode`, `pylance` ships with `pyright` tools, so you don't have to install it. Just set

```ini
"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict",
```

in your `settings.json` to reveal deeper errors.

Since your `package 2` is a 3rd-party package (installed, not local), `PEP 561` applies:

1. Your `my-utils` should be in your `site-packages` folder in your `venv`
2. You have a `py.typed`, which is good as that is required by [PEP 561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information):

> Package maintainers who wish to support type checking of their code MUST add a marker file named py.typed to their package supporting typing. This marker applies recursively: if a top-level package includes it, all its sub-packages MUST support type checking as well.

`stubgen` often provides incomplete typing, so a couple things to check:

1. Per [PEP 561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#partial-stub-packages)

> If a stub package distribution is partial it MUST include partial\n in a py.typed file

Comment: If I could give you a hug for this: If a stub package distribution is partial it MUST include partial\n in a py.typed file. I've lost so much time to this.

Comment: @MikeBarry Love hearing when I've helped someone! You are so welcome! Spread it forward. We all grow by helping each other. Cheers my friend!